# How do I patch libxml2 so it will compile with ICU support when using a prefix?

Tags: c, makefile, libxml2, icu

I'm trying to fix a bug in libxml2. I cannot get it to compile with `--with-icu` when using `--prefix=/Server/software`. I have submitted a [bug report here](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=663214), but I need to get it to compile for resolving a conflict when compiling PHP with intl support. I suspect it's a problem with the Makefile. My experience with Makefile's is limited. The desired result is coming up with a patch that can be submitted to the linked bug report.

The `--with-icu` flag causes `LIBXML_ICU_ENABLED` to be defined. The included code is supposed to resolve a conflict when including headers from both icu and libxml2 (specifically, both use UChar). The PHP plugin intl, activated with `--enable-intl`, requires icu. libxml2 is needed by PHP for DOM/XML functions.

There are two problems.

First, this config:

`./configure --prefix=/Server/software --enable-shared --enable-static --with-icu`

Results in:

`configure: error: libicu config program icu-config not found`

This happens because of this code in configure.in:

```
WITH_ICU=0
if test "$with_icu" != "yes" ; then
    echo Disabling ICU support
else
    ICU_CONFIG=icu-config
    if ${ICU_CONFIG} --cflags >/dev/null 2>&1
    then
        ICU_LIBS=`icu-config --ldflags`
        LDFLAGS="$LDFLAGS $ICU_LIBS"
        WITH_ICU=1
        echo Enabling ICU support
    else
        AC_MSG_ERROR([libicu config program icu-config not found])
    fi
fi
```

Specifically `ICUCONFIG=icu-config` isn't respecting `--prefix=/Server/software`. I can work around this by doing `export PATH=/Server/software/bin:$PATH`.

This "fixes" the ./configure problem.

Second, when I run `make` I get errors, the most relavent being:

`./include/libxml/encoding.h:31:26: error: unicode/ucnv.h: No such file or
directory`

The `unicode/uncv.h` file is in `/Server/software/include/unicode/uncv.h`. I suspect the compiler is looking for this file in the local directory and in my /usr directory.

This is what the error is referring to:

```
#ifdef LIBXML_ICU_ENABLED
#include <unicode/ucnv.h>
#endif
```

Clearly this is a path issue when using `--with-icu` and `--prefix=/Server/software`. Without `--with-icu` it compiles fine, but this is needed to resolve a define UChar conflict when compiling PHP with both icu and libxml2.

The result of `icu-config --cflags` is:

`-O2 -Wall -ansi -pedantic -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -Wmissing-prototypes -Wwrite-strings -Wno-long-long`

This is being piped into /dev/null.

The result of `icu-config --ldflags` is:

`-lpthread -lm   -L/Server/software/lib -licui18n -licuuc -licudata  -lpthread -lm`

What needs to be changed to resolve these issues?

Comment: I've posted a patch for the ICU_CONFIG problem: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=663214

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, take a look at where it's using icu-config. It should be doing something like `icu-config --cppflags` which should set `-I/Server/Software/include` or similar. You could work around it by setting CPPFLAGS to include such a parameter yourself.

Can you include the actual compile command line immediately before the error?

Sounds like a bug in libxml - it ought to search ${PREFIX}/bin for icu-config.

Also, ICU now exports `pkg-config` files, which are more of a standard way to find such items.

---

Try this before `WITH_ICU` :

```
    ICU_CPPFLAGS=`icu-config --cppflags`
    CPPFLAGS="$CPPFLAGS $ICU_CPPFLAGS"
```

---

**update** I'm going to quote Luke's last response. Glad it's working.

> I solved the linker problems, so now it all works. For this question
>   using libxml 2.7.7 was the solution. It seems OX X 10.6 ships with
>   2.7.8. So for it to work you have to compile libxml2 yourself with 2.7.7. The linker problems are solved by adding LIBS="-lresolv -lstdc++" just before PHP's ./configure. If installing to a non-standard location you also need to compile ICU with
>   --enable-rpath. I've accepted your answer. Feel free to update it with this information :). – Luke 17 hours ago

Comment: I updated the question to include the more relavent parts of configure.in and the output of icu-config when used in `configure.in`. It appears `icu-config --ldflags` is supposed to pass `/Server/software` to make the include work in `encoding.h`, but it's not getting through. Trying to find other packages that may do something similar.

Comment: Well that seems to have fixed the problem with building libxml2. But now my PHP's config fails with `checking whether libxml build works... no`. The relavant bit in config.log being `configure:21707: gcc -o conftest  -fvisibility=hidden  -no-cpp-precomp  -Wl,-rpath,/Server/software/lib -L/Server/software/lib conftest.c`. Without compiling libxml2 with `--with-icu` PHP is fine (if I don't include `--enable-intl`, which I need).

Comment: @Luke what does config.log in php say?  Intl uses ICU as I assume you are aware.  intl is using the same ICU you are using for libxml2, right?

Comment: Yes, same ICU. Here is config.log http://pastebin.com/qKezu2Z3 and here are the commands i'm using http://pastebin.com/dYQwUCm0 along with the patch file http://pastebin.com/ss0L6ZLw . Make sure the patch file and script are both in /Server if you run it.

Comment: @Luke line 092. and following look OK- the blank line is a bit strange - but it doesn't show the actual error. If you run 'gcc -o conftest .. ' yourself with the specified contents of conftest.c does it work? Need to find the actual error here.

Comment: conftest.c doesn't exist. There is a conftest.cpp though. Not sure why PHP is deciding to use "conftest.c" verses "conftest.cpp", but I think it has something to do with the "configure" file. For some reason libxml2 with icu seems to make it use the .c version, which doesn't exist.

Comment: @Luke configure creates conftest.c with:  "    char xmlInitParser();    int main() {      xmlInitParser();      return 0;    }"  and compiles it with:  gcc -o conftest -g -O2 -fvisibility=hidden  -no-cpp-precomp  -Wl,-rpath,/Server/software/lib -L/Server/software/lib conftest.c -lm  -lxml2 -lz -liconv -lm

can you try creating that file (without the quotes) and compiling/runnning it yourself and see what happens?

Comment: That works fine. No output. "conftest" binary is created. Something about adding icu support to libxml2 really throws PHP's build out of whack.

Comment: @Luke can you execute the conftest binary? Sounds like there's some problem with the autoconf not reporting back the actual issue. EDIT: I assumed that 'no output' meant the compiler, not the conftest binary.  The only other thing I thought of is that perhaps it is an older ICU version which outputs newlines in the icu-config output, since your config.log shows newlines in the compiler output. Which ICU are you using? (4.8.1.1 recommended)

Comment: I'm using 4.8.1.1. I discovered there is a problem with the most recent version of libxml2, 2.7.8. The --with-icu flag was introduced in 2.7.8. Stepping abck to 2.7.7 resolves all the issues I had before (including UChar). Now I'm having symbol issues with the PHP compiler. The intl extension appears to be the only C++ extension.

Comment: @Luke sounds like in the best case there's already a bug with libxml2's detection of ICU. Sorry, not sure what else to suggest here.

Comment: I solved the linker problems, so now it all works. For this question using libxml 2.7.7 was the solution. It seems OX X 10.6 ships with 2.7.8. So for it to work you have to compile libxml2 yourself with 2.7.7. The linker problems are solved by adding LIBS="-lresolv -lstdc++" just before PHP's ./configure. If installing to a non-standard location you also need to compile ICU with --enable-rpath. I've accepted your answer. Feel free to update it with this information :).

Comment: @Luke ICU bug:  http://bugs.icu-project.org/trac/ticket/10465 with work in progress code linked to the bugzilla  bug 663214 above.

Comment: `./configure --prefix=/path/libxml2 CPPFLAGS=-I/path/icu/include --with-icu`

The complete configure command should be like this.